# How do you debug broken home networks?

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I have a small home network, and I’m having trouble accessing one of the computers on that network. The home network is NAT’ed, and I've set up some port forwarding and a dynamic DNS.

- `rye` sits on my home network. Public-facing port 2222 of my router is forwarded to `rye`’s port 22.
- `sorghum` sits on my home network. Public-facing port 22 is forwarded to `sorghum`’s port 22.
- `teff` sits on an external network.

I now present the following strange scenario:

1. I can SSH from `teff` to `dmwit.duckdns.org:2222`, so I believe the dynamic DNS is working correctly, the port-forwarding to `rye` is working correctly, and `rye` is accepting connections from other computers correctly (i.e. isn’t blocking things at the firewall level).
2. I can SSH from `rye` to `dmwit.duckdns.org:22`, so I believe the port-forwarding to `sorghum` is working correctly, and `sorghum` is accepting connections from other computers correctly.
3. From `rye`, asking Netcat to connect to a port on `sorghum` that is being blocked by `sorghum`’s firewall results in “No route to host,” while from `teff` asking Netcat to connect to `dmwit.duckdns.org:22` results in “Connection timed out,” so I believe `sorghum`’s firewall is not blocking this connection.
4. I cannot SSH from `teff` to `sorghum` (the connection times out).

I find this a bit baffling; evidence suggests that each piece in the chain is working correctly, yet the whole chain is broken. I have two concrete questions that are somewhat unrelated to each other:

1. How can this kind of thing be debugged further? What tools can I use to find more detail on what's going wrong?
2. How do I fix it so that I can ssh from teff to sorghum?

**EDIT:** I’ve found a [vaguely related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108162/ssh-connection-timed-out-its-not-client-or-server-what-now) which suggested trying Traceroute. On `teff` I can see a significant difference between the Traceroute outputs for ports 22 and 2222:

```
% traceroute -p 2222 -T dmwit.duckdns.org
traceroute to dmwit.duckdns.org (75.164.159.92), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gw-40.galois.com (192.168.40.1)  13.722 ms  13.723 ms  17.016 ms
 2  66.162.129.25 (66.162.129.25)  17.957 ms  18.106 ms  18.289 ms
 3  64-129-238-66.static.twtelecom.net (64.129.238.66)  18.949 ms sea2-pr2-xe-0-3-0-0.us.twtelecom.net (66.192.243.34)  19.250 ms 64-129-238-66.static.twtelecom.net (64.129.238.66)  19.242 ms
 4  64.132.69.2 (64.132.69.2)  20.052 ms  20.291 ms  20.284 ms
 5  ptld-agw1.inet.qwest.net (67.14.49.2)  22.658 ms  22.942 ms  22.932 ms
 6  207.225.86.146 (207.225.86.146)  22.924 ms  8.583 ms  8.591 ms
 7  * * *
 8  75-164-159-92.ptld.qwest.net (75.164.159.92)  31.056 ms  29.508 ms  29.714 ms
% traceroute -p 22 -T dmwit.duckdns.org -m 60
traceroute to dmwit.duckdns.org (75.164.159.92), 60 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gw-40.galois.com (192.168.40.1)  1.660 ms  5.667 ms  5.912 ms
 2  66.162.129.25 (66.162.129.25)  5.901 ms  12.563 ms  12.555 ms
 3  64-129-238-66.static.twtelecom.net (64.129.238.66)  14.227 ms sea2-pr2-xe-0-3-0-0.us.twtelecom.net (66.192.243.34)  12.796 ms  12.787 ms
 4  64.132.69.2 (64.132.69.2)  12.778 ms  12.769 ms  12.762 ms
 5  ptld-agw1.inet.qwest.net (67.14.49.2)  13.955 ms  13.946 ms  13.937 ms
 6  207.225.86.146 (207.225.86.146)  13.931 ms  10.297 ms  10.256 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
<snip>
```

The second one goes on like that for 20 more lines (and continues further if you increase the maximum hop count). I’m not 100% sure how to interpret this, so add a third question:

3. What does this traceroute output mean?

Comment: The traceroute is a red herring I think.  In summary, you can ssh to sorghum's public IP from inside your network, but not from outside.  This is interesting as it is usually the opposite.  It seems that port 22 is blocked on the outside interface.  When you try this from internal, it doesn't apply the block as you ingress on the inside interface.  To confirm, could you port forward 22222 to 22 for sorghum?

Comment: @Paul After adding a port-forward for external port 22222 to sorghum's 22, dmwit.duckdns.org:22 and dmwit.duckdns.org:22222 appear to behave identically from teff: ssh/netcat connections time out, and traceroute prints as many `* * *` lines as I care to ask for.

Comment: Can you ssh from rye to sorghum using your internal LAN IP addresses? I would try that just for a sanity check to make sure that SSH is working on sorghum without having to go out of your network and back in.

Comment: @jdwfly The fact that I can ssh from rye to sorghum using dyndns is strong evidence to me that SSH is working on sorghum. Nevertheless, for completeness, I have confirmed just now that using the internal IP instead of a DNS also works fine to ssh from rye to sorghum.

Comment: Thanks to all the answers added since the bounty was offered. It was difficult choosing a winner -- since none so far have solved my problem (due in part I think to the limited time I ended up having to debug this). The answer I chose addressed all three questions in turn and suggested the most different ways doing network debugging, but all answers were helpful in their own way. If I had the points I would have opened additional bounties to formally recognize your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that there is no outgoing SSH block at the teff end? You demonstrated you could connect to a home system on port 2222 from teff, but there could be an outgoing block on port 22. If you have not verified that outgoing port 22 connections from teff are possible, then try `ssh github.com` from teff. You should see a prompt regarding the key for github.com. Have you verified that you have an appropriate firewall rule at the demarcation point between the external network and your internal home network that will allow an incoming connection from teff's IP address on port 22? I see that dmwit.duckdns.org is not open to connectivity from the Internet on port 22 and it seems you've only verified that sorghum is accessible from an internal home network address, which doesn't necessarily mean that there's an appropriate firewall rule that will allow port 22 connections from elsewhere. Look at the firewall log on sorghum; do you see anything in the log indicating an attempt to connect to port 22 from teff?  You could attempt a connection from a system other than teff using the [SSH server connectivity test](http://www.infobyip.com/sshservertest.php) and examine the sorghum firewall log afterwards to see if any activity was logged, if sorghum should at least be reachable on port 22 from the Internet, even if the firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I can ssh from teff to github -- at least to the extent github allows this ("You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."). I will look into the firewall logs shortly.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, check sorghum's firewall log; if it isn't logging connections to port 22, turn on logging and if there is a router/firewall at the edge of your home network between sorghum and teff, if it provides any logging mechanism that could help, turn on logging there as well. Unfortunately, many [SOHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_office/home_office) routers have limited or no logging capability, but if you can confirm that device is seeing the attempted port 22 connections from teff that is a useful piece of data.

Comment: It seems firewalld doesn't log accepted/rejected connections, so that wasn't very helpful. I clicked a button to turn on logging on my router... and my remote connection to my home network promptly dropped. =P I will do some more tests once I have been able to go home, fix whatever I did to the router, and come back to an external network.

Comment: Okay, quick update: it seems from the logging that my connections from teff are at least making it to the router, which is a promising sign. That seems like good evidence that something on sorghum is causing the problem. I tried turning off the firewall on sorghum entirely briefly, which didn't seem to help. I will look into possible problems with SELinux next, though I've run out of time to troubleshoot this for today.

Comment: @DanielWagner note: if you don't see anything in `tcpdump` on `sorghum` (as you see it on `rye`), it indicates that problem is **before** `sorghum` (that is, on your home router). Make sure you've specified the correct network interface if you have several of them, though (eg. `tcpdump -i eth0`)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up sshd to listen on another port other than port 22 on sorghum ( > 1024) . This may be something provider specific either on the outgoing of teffs side or the incoming of rye's/sorghum side. Some providers block certain reserved ports, a good example would be port 25 smtp because no providers enjoy dealing with spammers scanning their networks for open relays.  Anyhow I'm convinced this may be the reason, the port is showing up as filtered in a basic syn test which likely means it could be being filtered at the provider level on rye/sorghums side
(ingress)

["Filtered means that these ports were identified as being stopped by something along the network path. It could be a firewall on the target, but it could also be filtering rules on any of the intermediate hosts between the audit and target machines."](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-test-your-firewall-configuration-with-nmap-and-tcpdump)

I was able to confirm the same filtering behavior with multiple addresses within the same network. I do suggest reading the AUP policies of your service provider though as you will be likely restricted from using the default port. Good luck to you sir.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I swapped from forwarding external port 22 to forwarding external port 2223 (but still to internal port 22); after this change, port 2223 doesn't seem to behave any differently than port 22 did before the test.

Answer (score 1):

1. you would use tools like tcpdump(8) and/or wireshark(1) to see what packets are arriving to and going from problematic hosts. So if you see TCP SYN packet arriving, but no answer being sent, that is due to local firewall (or routing). But if you don't see TCP SYN packet arriving at all, it means some firewall dropped it before it got to your host. For example your router default firewall configuration, or your ISP that deems running services on your hosts it violation of its ToS and/or security risk.
2. I'd suggest changing public-facing port `22` to for example `2223`. If it works, it means either ISP firewall, or your home router blocks port 22.
3. it means that router at hop 6,7 or 8 (it is ambiguous due to silent router at 7) is dropping packets with destination port 22 (and not those with port 2222). Again, it could be your ISP firewall or your home router firewall or local configuration (for example, router might reserve port 22 for itself for remote management, and drop connection to it from external ports). I'd suspect local router. Again, easiest to check is to change public facing port to 2223 for `sorghum`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! tcpdump appears to me to show that no connection request is making it all the way through to `sorghum`. I also forwarded external port 2223 rather than external port 22, but that did not appear to make any difference -- ssh connections to port 2223 from `teff` failed in exactly the same way.

Comment: @DanielWagner **tcpdump** will show packets "on the wire" before they hit local firewall or app, so if you don't see anything in tcpdump, then router didn't send anything there. `rye` and `sorghum` should behave the same now, so it strongly indicates that your home router is not setup exactly the same for both of them. Maybe one is declared DMZ host or there is some leftover configuration (MAC firewall or such). Perhaps clearing router config and entering redirections again should help you make indentical configs for both hosts.